# What is the simple standard error for MCMC?

Tags: bayesian, variance, standard-deviation, standard-error, markov-chain-montecarlo

Simply put: suppose that we have observed $X=\left\{ X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}\right\}$. We then need to calculate some statistic $T$ using MCMC, using $M$ loops (By "loops" I mean the number of times the chain is repeated to come up with a sensible posterior). We then repeat this entire experiment $P$ times as a part of some sort of simulation study.

What is a sensible estimate of the standard error of $T$?

At the moment, I am calculating the standard error without considering $n$ - so I do not think this is correct.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any burn-in (/warm-up)? Are you skipping or using all values in the sequence?

Comment: If you repeat the experiment $P$ times, this is an iid experiment, so you can use standard methods to estimate the average over the $P$ repetitions. I do not think $n$ should appear explicitly in the standard error formula.

Comment: I think you can just use the sample standard deviation. That's what I do

Comment: Glen - I am using a burn-in period, but I assumed it is 0 for simplicity

Xi'an - if this is the case, then surely there would be more information using 10,000 actual observations Vs. 10?

Answer (score 2):

I know very little frequentist stats so I can't say anything about the standard error, but I have come across an estimate of the variance that might help.

Suppose after burnin you have $C$ chains of $S$ samples each. Then define the between-chain variance as

$$B = \frac{S}{C-1} \sum_c (\bar y_c - \bar y)^2$$

where $\bar y_c$ is the mean of chain $c$ and $\bar y$ is the overall mean. Define also the within-chain variance

$$W = \frac{1}{C} \sum_c \frac{1}{S-1} \sum_s (y_{cs} - \bar y_c)^2$$

where $y_{sc}$ is the $s$th sample in the $c$th chain. Then under stationarity, an unbiased estimate of the variance of $y$ is

$$\hat V = \frac{S-1}{S}W + \frac{1}{S}B$$

This is originally from [Gelman & Rubin 1992](https://stat.duke.edu/~scs/Courses/Stat376/Papers/ConvergeDiagnostics/GelmanRubinStatSci1992.pdf), Section 2.2, though this particular notation is from [MLAPP](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/) section 24.4.3.1.

Comment: Note that this is just the weighted average of sample variances

Comment: Thanks Andy. How about the number of observations which the MCMC used to come up with $y_{i}$?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: For example, we simulate 100 observations from some $i.i.d N(0,1)$, and we wish to calculate the AR(1) coefficient using MCMC (obviously this is going to be 0, but we want MCMC to prove it). So we use a MCMC sampler with 10,000 loops (0 burn-in for simplicity) and have 500 independant chains running at once. How does the 100 come into play here when calculating the s.e. of the AR(1) coefficient?

Comment: Why do you have 500 independent chains to take 100 samples? If it was a typo and you meant to say 100 independent chains, then $C = 100$ and $S = 10,000$.

Comment: 100 samples of data. So I give you a vector 100x1 in MATLAB, and ask you to use 500 independent chains with 10,000 loops each to find the posterior of the AR(1) coefficient. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Note: I am starting to think this is "automagically" taken into consideration, and there is no need to adjust for this number

Comment: @akkp The variance/standard-error described in this answer is the variance of a **single** step in the MCMC after taking a large number of steps; i.e. it estimates the variance of the posterior for the parameter $\sigma^2 = \int (x - \mu)^2 P(x) dx$ for $\mu = \int x P(x) dx$. It probably gets more accurate the more samples you take, but shouldn't change. This is not the variance of the mean of the samples, which is perhaps what frequentists often refer to by standard error?